# How can I re-enable the edit link?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I had some bad edits on some questions or answers, and now the edit link for editing other's posts is disabled.

What can I do to re-enable it?

Comment: You need to wait the ban out. It should be about 1 week.

Comment: You wait for a week. In the meantime, try to figure out *why* you were edit-banned. Most importantly, try to learn from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us take a look at your rejected edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1823449

  The edit is not equivalent to other existing alternatives in the post. The reject is justified.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1834957

  This rejection seems to happen due to a reviewer editing the post then mark your edit as not helpful. I think it is reasonable: although you somewhat fixed the formatting, the indentation is still horrible.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1839936

  This **shouldn't have been rejected**. The added information is from [the comment of the author of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768156/how-to-stop-a-div-from-automatically-scrolling-to-bottom#comment22413414_15768356).

  Actually, you should have mentioned that the information comes from comment. Otherwise, reviewers would not realize where the information comes from.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1842385

  I am not sure about the tags, but the post still have other things that can be improved, such as capitalization and spacing. Improve as many things as possible, since it wastes the reviewer's time by making a minor edit.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1848218

  The changes is quite random and too minor. The indentation could have been corrected.